# Does $\sum^{∞}_{k=1} \frac{4k^k}{2^{k^2}}$ converge absolutely?

Tags: calculus, absolute-convergence

I was wondering if you guys could judge my reasoning and let me know if am correct in finding if this series converges absolutely or conditionally.

$$\sum^{∞}_{k=1} \frac{4k^k}{2^{k^2}}$$

I decided to use the root test because of the k's in the exponent.

$$\lim_{n → ∞} {(\frac{|4n^n|}{|2^{n^2}|}})^{1/n} → \lim_{n → ∞} {\frac{|4^{1/n}n^{n/n}|}{|2^{n^2/n}|}} → \lim_{n → ∞} \frac{|n|}{|2^{n}|}$$

Since the $\lim_{n → ∞} \frac{|n|}{|2^{n}|} = 0$ by growth rates, $\sum^{∞}_{k=1} \frac{|4k^k|}{|2^{k^2}|}$ converges. Which means $\sum^{∞}_{k=1} \frac{4k^k}{2^{k^2}}$ converges absolutely.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: For what it is worth, the sum of the first seven terms give slightly more than $3.22693775$ and adding more terms will not change that last decimal place

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Since all terms are positive, conditional convergence is (by definition) out of the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it converges absolutely.

A few points:

- Instead of the arrow $\rightarrow$, it is more common to use the equal sign $=$.
- You implicitly use the following results:
  $$
  \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{4}=1,\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=0\;,
  $$
  which is okay if you know why they are true.
- You could omit the absolute value in various places since every term is non-negative.